# Pull known-good static files out of a buggy git branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-rebase

I recently inherited a ruby project. The dev before introduced some bugs that made it on to staging. Now there are a few static pages that need to get on prod by tomorrow sans the problematic code. What is the best way to approach this? I have looked at git rebase but I'm not sure that is what I want to do or how to do it properly in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the specific commit those pages were introduced in, you could `git cherry-pick` those commits out into a new branch and switch to that temporarily.

Otherwise, an interactive rebase -- `git rebase -i` -- will allow you to select the commits you want to keep and those you want to discard. This should, of course, only be done after having made full backups.